# Sending SMS from Matlab and make sure all the recipients get the SMS

Tags: excel, matlab, at-command, sms-gateway

I have create a `matlab` code, which gets phone numbers from the column `O` of an excel file, then, it sends an `sms` to them.

It works but there is problem when sending the `sms`. It seems that `matlab` doesn't wait until my modem is done with the first `sms`. So, when the excel column has 8 phone numbers, the modem can only send an `sms` to the first 3-4 of them. This is the code:

```
[num MP]=xlsread('D:\Ray\Data.xls',1,'O:O');     %get the phone numbers from excel

MP=MP(cellfun(@(x)not(isempty(x)),MP));          %remove the empty cells

[row column]=size(MP);                           %get the number of the phone numbers

t1=char(13);                                     %(for doing 'enter')
t2=char(26);                                     %(for doing 'ctrl+z)
sms='hello';                                     %SMS content
t4=sprintf('%s',sms);
t5='AT+CMGF=1';                                  %for text mode

s = serial('COM5');                              

s.baudrate=9600;

fopen(s);                                        %open serial COM5 (my modem)

    fprintf(s,'%s', t5);
    fprintf(s,'%s', t1);

    for q=1:row

        t3=sprintf('AT+CMGS="%s"',char(MP(q)));

        fprintf(s,'%s', t3);
        fprintf(s,'%s', t1);    
        fprintf(s,'%s', t4);
        fprintf(s,'%s', t2);

    end

fclose(s)
```

I was wondering how to make `matlab` wait until my modem is done with the first phone numbers before trying to send the `sms` to the second number, so all the phone numbers can get the `sms`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be some response from the modem, if you don't find anything in the documentation simply try reading from the com port. Probably one char for each processed sms, reading it will block matlab until the sms is processed.

Comment: @Daniel. I try to do what you suggest, if I am not mistaken, this is the code:    

    global B;
    global C;

    C=s.BytesAvailable;
    if(C>0), B=fread(s,C,'char'); end



...there are still recipients that don't receive the sms. But less than before. So it works better than before. Thanks Mr Daniel

Comment: You are reading non-blocking. This is typically the right choice, but here you want to block until you get a response. Don't check if bytes are available, call `B=fread(s,1,'char');` and matlab will wait until sending is confirmed (assuming the response is a 1 byte message). Keep in mind, that maybe setting up is confirmed as well.

Comment: @Daniel: Is there another way to do that beside using 

B=fread(s,1,'char')   ?  


I've tried it but it doesn't really work.  Recently I use Hyperterminal to check the message from modem after each sms sent. 


The message is +CMGS:228.  And the next sms sent, there will be message:  +CMGS:229,  and so on.



Is there a way to make sure matlab continue the looping only after seeing the message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a very simple solution, if you know how much time sending an SMS will reasonably take, you can force Matlab to wait by using a `pause` statement. For example, if sending a single SMS takes ~3 seconds, you add

```
pause(3)
```

into the loop.

Note that if for whatever reason, sending takes much longer than anticipated, this approach will fail (or you have to set pauses that are so long that the code becomes unusable). A smarter, but more involved solution is to query the modem or the COM port as suggested by @Daniel in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Mr Jonas. It works perfectly. All the recipients can receive the SMS.
I also turn off the windows firewall of this laptop.

Comment: Keep in mind, that this will fail if you have a short network outage. If you want reliability, you have to read the responses.

Comment: @Daniel: Completely agreed. I will edit your caveat explicitly into my answer.

Comment: @Daniel,@Jonas:  yes... the 'Pause' doesn't work when the sending time is longer than usual. I've experienced it now.

Answer (score 0):

When executing AT commands with a modem you should always follow the recommendations from your modem hardware manufacturer. They generally recommend wait (sleep) times and most definitely you should ensure that your code waits for a command termination code like OK or ERROR et al.

Answer (score 0):

In my comment, I assumed the response message has 1 byte. Your modem answers with more than 1 byte, thus when sending the second SMS there is already a byte from the first SMS in the queue. You have to get the full answer, which seems to have 9 bytes.

```
for q=1:row
    t3=sprintf('AT+CMGS="%s"',char(MP(q)));

    fprintf(s,'%s', t3);
    fprintf(s,'%s', t1);    
    fprintf(s,'%s', t4);
    fprintf(s,'%s', t2);

    %read all 9 answer bytes
    B=fread(s,9,'char');
end
```

Obviously you should check the answer `B`.

Comment: I've used the codes, and then check the content of B. I even tried    B=fread(s,60,'char')    and it returns exactly 60 values, not 9.         



    B =

    65
    84
    43
    67
    77
    71
    70
    61
    49
    13
    13
    10
    79
    75
    13
    10
    65
    84
    43
    67
    77
    71
    83
    61
    34
    43
    54
    50
    56
    57
    56
    54
    56
    48
    57
    53
    55
    51
    34
    13
    13
    10
    62
    32
   104
   101
   108
   108
   111
    13
    10
    13
    10
    43
    67
    77
    71
    83
    58
    32

Comment: @Ray: Then you probably need the documentation for your modem to check when it sends what message.

Comment: May be that code does not only read the last response of modem, but also all the previous responses and all command I have typed.

Comment: @Ray: The code gets everything from your input buffer, regardless when it came in. This might be possible.

Comment: Okay Mr Daniel, thanks very much for your help and explanation today.